# Openpyxl casillas con formullas

Tags: python, excel

Cuando quiero obtener el valor de una casilla que contiene una formula
[image: Casilla]

> casilla.value 
>   obtengo la formula y no el numero dentro de la casilla

¿Cómo puedo referirme al numero dentro de la casilla y no a la formula dentro de ella?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenPyxl no evalúa las fórmulas si abres la excel con `openpyxl.load_workbook(fichero)`, como [dice aqui](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-formulae) en su documentación. En ese caso no tienes forma de acceder al valor numérico.

Pero si lo abres con `openpyxl.load_workbook(fichero, data_only=True)`, hace lo contrario. El atributo `.value` de cada celda te da su valor numérico y en este caso no tienes forma de acceder a la fórmula. **Cuidado** porque aún en este caso `openpyxl` no evalúa la fórmula, sino que lee un valor que Excel guardó allí la última vez que la evaluó. Si con `openpyxl` cambias los datos de alguna celda, los valores de las celdas con fórmulas **no se actualizan**.

Si necesitaras ambas cosas, deberías abrir la hoja dos veces en dos instancias diferentes que podrías procesar en paralelo.

Si sólo quieres los datos y no manipular la Excel, y vas a tener que procesarlos de alguna forma después, te recomiendo usar Pandas, que usa openpyxl por debajo para leer la Excel y te proporciona después un DataFrame mucho más útil para visualizar los datos y obtener estadíssticas, gráficas, etc.